# How to combine a Qt-GUI with ROS?

Tags: qt, ros

I'm currently working on a Qt-GUI with which I plan to remote control a robot. The robot is ros-controlled and equipped with multiple cameras. The topic is completely new to me and I just started learning both Qt and ROS and have some basic questions. I didn't make any progress googling around  so I finally decided to post it here:

- How can I connect data from ROS with Qt? So let's say I kind of want to live-stream the recordings of the cameras into my GUI. How is the general procedure there?
- I've seen this [ROS Qt Creator Plug-in](https://ros-qtc-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Is that something I want to use for this project?

Thanks a lot to everyone answering.

This is my first post here so I hope I didn't mess anything up or flouted forum regulations.

Edit 1: I am working with C++.
Edit 2: In case it helps you giving me advice; the *rostopic type* of the camera topic is *sensor_msgs/Image*.

Comment: Do you work with C++ or Python (PyQt)?

Comment: I am working with C++.

Comment: There are many tutorials in the web. This one is very good: https://www.cnblogs.com/casperwin/p/6206193.html

Comment: I actually had a look into this already but apparently didn't manage to set up the path correctly; at least I didn't get the expected output out of the 'which qmake' command. Thanks a lot for pointing me in this direction though, I'll try to get get this working!

Comment: I think you should try to ask specific questions to get some help. Show what you've tried and where you stuck.

Comment: I'm working on that tutorial but already get confused after the first couple of steps: I have Qt installed in a different directory and also its a newer Version so I tried to edit the commands he gives. So when starting the Creator via terminal it opens the old Version (3.something, I have 4.8). Not sure if that is normal. Then in step 4) I'm supposed to install a couple of ROS packages. I'm using ROS kinetic though and there doesn't seem to be a complementary kinetic package?! I guess I can't just use the indigo packages?

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, since the images are coming over the *sensor_msgs/Image* topic, using ROS with OpenCV's [cv_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) in the Qt application to receive the the incoming image stream from ROS into the Qt-GUI is a good start. There are several tutorials that cover integrating OpenCV into a Qt project. An important advice is to keep track of the image properties (size, color format, etc.), which will help in displaying the image properly in the GUI. Disclaimer: I have worked with Qt libraries on the Python side, not with C++.

As for question 2, the information for setting up, building, and running the code within the Qt-Creator can be very convenient. There are times where it is prudent to use an IDE to build, run, and debug code (to deal with memory management, segmentation faults, etc.), while other for other times running "catkin_make" or "catkin build" in the root directory when the hardware is minimal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. I'm definitely going to have a look into OpenCV then!